# Lucene: queryparser vs phrasequery or termquery

Tags: java, search, lucene, full-text-search

what are the advantages of not using queryparser and using phrasequery or termquery? It seems to me you can use queryparser to replace any of those?

For example, if I want to search for a exact phrase, I can do:

```
String searchString = "\"word1 word2\"";
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_46,"content", analyzer);
Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString);
```

or if I want to search for 2 terms, I can do

```
String searchString = "word1* AND word2*";
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_46,"content", analyzer);
Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString);
```

Currently, I am only using queryparser and it is working for me, but is this the correct way of using Lucene?

Comment: QueryParser is fine until it isn't. There is nothing wrong with using it, but there are types of queries that go beyond QueryParser's capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Main disadvantage of not using `QueryParser` is following (it's especially the case when using Solr/Elastic):

When you're creating the `TermQuery`, something like this:

```
Query q = new TermQuery("text", "keyword")
```

the problem will be that you need to apply analyzers/filters manually. Let's say user types `KeyWord`, then if you just pass it into `TermQuery`, you will not find anything, if during indexing time you were using lowercasing. Of course the lowercasing is simple, but do you want to apply everything in the code for stemming/nramming, etc., and not relying on existing functionality from analyzers/filters?

Comment: so you are saying it is better to use QueryParser because it is easier to apply analyzers/filters?

Comment: @help, yes. How you will apply stemming for example? manually will do some calls on terms?